# login authentication script error

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to write a login authentication for a web based MIS. Below is the code i use.however, this doesn't login when given the username "admin" and the password "12345" even though that record was put in the data table.

This is the  SQL code for  the table:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
last_login DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

When I  put `echo $stmt->num_rows;` 0 is returned, so I guess it means  it found no matches in the  database. Can anyone help me out?

#### Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Sanitize incoming username and password
$username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Connect to the MySQL server
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "qwerty", "MIS");

// Determine whether an account exists matching this username and password
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = ? and password = md5(?)");

// Bind the input parameters to the prepared statement
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); 

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// Store the result so we can determine how many rows have been returned
$stmt->store_result();


if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

// Bind the returned user ID to the $id variable
$stmt->bind_result($id); 
$stmt->fetch();

// Update the account's last_login column
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET last_login = NOW() WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('d', $id); 
$stmt->execute();

  session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

// Redirect the user to the home page
header('Location: http://localhost/');
}


?>
```

Comment: when you inserted a password from phpmyadmin, are you sure you entered the md5 hash value? because your code searches for the hash value and not the password string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code appears to be okay

When you enter a new record, make sure you don't enter the plain password string, **you should enter the md5 hash value of the password** since your code looks for the hash value and not the
original string.